# Magento Promotions - Payment Method

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, shopping-cart, coupon

I would like to know if there is a plugin for applying discounts on the sub total when a certain bank credit card is being used for transaction. I am planning to connect different banks to my webstore. When a customer is purchasing a product, he/she can enter their valid credit card of the specified bank to check if they can use the discount on the sub total.

There are any plugin or cart rule condition for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Also, asking for extensions is off-topic too. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity,How can you say that it's not related programming questiong, Please read again my question I am asking about particular payment method discount programming. Hope you understand.

Comment: There is nothing programming related in your question. You're asking for a plugin (which is off-topic) or you're asking to configure a application (which is also off-topic). You need to ask a specific question about programming. Perhaps have a read of the [help/on-topic] to see what's on-topic.

Comment: No Plugin in open cart